# PermissionDeniedError: Can't open file '/etc/debian_version'

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench

Estoy usando **Ubuntu 20.04**. en mi proyecto actual estoy usando **Workbench** para la base de datos, pero tengo este error:

> error de permiso denegado: no se puede abrir 'etc / debian_version'

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

Esto suele ocurrir cuando sobre cargas o esperas mucho tiempo usando un túnel ssh, debes cerrar Workbench y los procesos, revisar que mysql este corriendo, puedes conectarte por la consola y mirar que la conexión funcione así:
Dando clic derecho y eligiendo la opción que se muestra a continuación

[image]

Luego de verificar que si funcione mediante consola, si no funciona puedes ir a otra conexión que ya tengas establecida y probar que funcione.

Vuelves a abrir la conexión que quieres usar.